# How to deploy One Touch Digital Persona SDK for .net Project?

Tags: c#, sdk, fingerprint

I have installed One Touch Digital Persona SDK and done a C# project. Now I want to deploy the application to other computer without installing One Touch SDK.

What files do I need to deploy in my project and if I need to register a dll in order to get it working on a computer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a dll which has added references to the Digital Persona dlls. I needed to get an ActiveX Control working with the fingerprint device. I then created a "Setup project" in .NET and had it include the one fingerprintScanner.dll file. The .NET automatically saw the references as dependencies and added them in to the "Setup project".

So at least with the U are U 4500 device, all the user has to do is plug it into the USB port ( which installs the device drivers through Windows ) then they run my compiled setup project ( a Windows installer .msi ).  It will install the .dlls and also I had the .dlls set to register to COM in the setup project so I can see them to create an ActiveX Control in the browser.

Luckily, I only have to worry about IE and Windows for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the SDK on other computers. You have to include the redistributable DLL files which comes with the SDK along with the project.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Chandra. I'm editing your answer to remove the "txt spk", and the greetings/thank yous. Please, use proper English when posting to SO.

Comment: For the benefit of the community, I suggest that you continue your discussion here on SO instead of going "offline".

Comment: I need exactly what you said, I have a .net project that will be using Digital Persona and dont want the user to install a separate Setup for Digital Persona, want to include that in my project DLL's is that possible? What dll's do I need to add?